# Large Deviation Bounds for Number of Forests (or Tutte polynomial) in G(n,p)

Tags: random-graphs, co.combinatorics, reference-request

Does anyone know of results/references related to large deviation bounds on the number of subforests (or the Tutte polynomial) in G(n,p) (Erdos-Renyi random graphs)?

Comment: I now know of results about the expectation and variance of the number of *spanning trees* in G(n,p) (http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1772444) and the expected number of forests in G(n,p). But still no results on large deviation bounds for the number of forests.